# Make default tab 'edit' for content type

Tags: plone

Is there a way to make the default selected tab for a particular (developed) content type 'edit' when users are logged in?

Comment: I would imagine you can set the default_view to 'edit' in the xml for the type.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an approach similar to the one used in the Link content type.

assuming you are using Grok, create a browser view like this:

```py
from five import grok
from plone import api
from my.contenttype.interfaces import IMyContentType

grok.templatedir('templates')

class MyContentTypeRedirectView(grok.View):
    grok.context(IMyContentType)
    grok.name('my_redirect_view')
    grok.require('zope2.View')

    def render(self):
        """Redirect to the target URL if the user is logged in."""
        context = self.context
        mtool = api.portal.get_tool('portal_membership')
        is_anonymous = mtool.isAnonymousUser()

        if is_anonymous:
            return context.restrictedTraverse('@@view')()
        else:
            return context.restrictedTraverse('@@edit')()
```

in your content type FTI XML file set the following:

```xml
<property name="default_view">my_redirect_view</property>
<property name="default_view_fallback">False</property>
<property name="view_methods">
  <element value="my_redirect_view" />
</property>
```

this way when the user is anonymous it will be redirected to the standard view and when it is logged in, it will be redirected to the edit view.

you can see code similar to this in the [sc.banner](https://github.com/simplesconsultoria/sc.banner) custom content type.